# Rprof fails on Bash for Windows

Tags: r, profiling

I'm trying to profile a function in R. But I get the error:

`Fatal error: setting profile timer failed`

When trying to run the code

`f <- function() mean(c(1:100))
tmp <- tempfile()
Rprof(tmp)
f()
Rprof(NULL)`

I'm using R 3.3.1 on Bash for Windows.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: The error message means that `setitimer(ITIMER_PROF...` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to timer syscalls not implemented yet https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/307

It should be fixed on next insider build and also on the Creators Update (release expected on March 2017)